# jquery simplicity function

Tags: jquery, function

I wonder how I could simplify this function. In first condition i have own function contentClose() with callback. I know, that I can create new small function with load ($('#content').load("cz/"+url+".h ETC...)  , but I wonder different way. Is it exist?

```
        if($('nav').hasClass('on')) {
            contentClose(function() {
              $('#content').load("cz/"+url+".htm", function() {
                        $('#gallery').photobox('a',{ time:0 });
                        $('#gallery li:first-child a').click();
                });  
            });
        } else {
            $('#content').load("cz/"+url+".htm", function() {
                    $('#gallery').photobox('a',{ time:0 });
                    $('#gallery li:first-child a').click();
            });    
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: No, making a new small function seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
function contentLoad(){
    $('#content').load("cz/"+url+".htm", function() {
        $('#gallery').photobox('a',{ time:0 });
        $('#gallery li:first-child a').click();
    });  
}

if($('nav').hasClass('on')) {
    contentClose( contentLoad );
} else {
    contentLoad();
}
```

Comment: It think you could also do `contentClose(contentLoad);`